# how to enable vs2010 layout tool bar?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, layout, reporting-services, toolbar

I installed VS 2010 premium recently. My problem is that there are several features they appear disabled particularly layout toolbar for example aligning, spacing etc. I think I am missing something to make them enabled. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: For the disabled layout toolbar issue at least, assuming you are writing a Windows Forms application, have you made sure then you're not running the application at the same time that you are trying to make changes to it and that you are looking at the design view of the form rather than the code?

Comment: Hi Malice, I am using SSRS. Whenever I need to use the layout toolbar, for some unknown reason, looks always grey (disabled).

Comment: Okay, the same questions from my previous comment should still apply. Have you verified them? Also have you verified that you have something selected in design view when you are trying to use the layout options?